# what does the sequence below converge to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$ \frac {n−1}{ n^2 + 1} + \frac{ n − 1}{n^2 + 2} + · · · + \frac {n − 1} { n^2+ n} $$

Can I use the sandwich theorem?

$$ \frac {n^2−n}{ n^2 + n} < a_n < \frac {n^2−n}{ n^2 + 1} $$

Comment: BTW, It's not a sequence, it's a sum.

Comment: for me it is a sequence where each member of the sequence is a finite sum.

Comment: You multiplied the lower bound by the number of terms, but missed doing so for the upper bound, which should be $\frac{n^2-n}{n^2+1}$.

Comment: @robjohn I don't really understand why am multiplying by n

Comment: Because there are $n$ terms in the sum, ranging from $\frac{n-1}{n^2+n}$ to $\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}$.

Comment: How do I apply the sandwich theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: The sandwich theorem and

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2+n}\le\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}+\frac{n-1}{n^2+2}+\ldots+\frac{n-1}{n^2+n}\le\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2+1}$$

I changed the original sequence from $n^2 -1$ to $n^2 +1$ for the first fraction

Comment: Then how would I apply the sandwich theorem?

Comment: (+1) I have no idea why this was downvoted. There was a typo originally, but that was corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as follows:
Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ defined as 
\begin{equation*}
a_n := \frac {n−1}{ n^2 + 1} + \frac{ n − 1}{n^2 + 2} + · · · + \frac {n − 1} { n^2+ n}.
\end{equation*}
Does $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge?!

$a_n$ consists of $n$ summands and you can estimate each of the from above by $\frac{n-1}{n^2+1}$. Then you can show that $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Comment: what do you mean by summand?

Comment: A "summand" for me is when you add two numbers each number is a summand, maybe there are better words in english for that.

Comment: This would be my interpretation also (+1 for that). But to prove the convergence you also need to give a sandwiching lower bound. I'm sure you can manage (or leave that for the OP to do).

Comment: what does this sign mean := ?

Comment: $:=$ means "defined as".
Yes, of course we also need a lower bound. But it is pretty easy to see such one.

Comment: @JonasLenz is the lower bound n-1/n^2+n

Comment: Each summand of $a_n$ is bounded from below by $\frac{n-1}{n^2+n}$. As $a_n$ consists of $n$ summands you need to multiply this with $n$ to get a lower bound for $a_n$.

Comment: @JonasLenz so the lower bound is n^2 - n/ n^2 +n

Comment: which is 0.....

Comment: @BigG No, that lower bound neither isn't  zero nor even it converges to zero...

Comment: @DonAntonio how would I find the limit of convergence?

Comment: You need to find out what the lower and upper bound converge to. In case they are equal (this will be the case) you have found the limit of $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by the sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the following inequality $$\frac{n-1}{n^2+n} \le \frac{n-1}{n^2+r}  \le \frac{n-1}{n^2} \quad \big( 0 \le r \le n \big )$$